# UWP AutoSuggestBox search upper/lower case?

Tags: uwp

I have this code, where i want to search the AutoSuggestBox, and i want to search upper and lower case. 
The line with StartsWith... can search upper and lower!
The line with Contains... can't

I want contains, but where i can search upper and lower case, how do i do?

```
   private string[] GetSuggestions(string text)
    {
        string[] result = null;
        result = suggestions.Where(x => x.StartsWith(text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ToArray();
        //result = suggestions.Where(x => x.Contains(text)).ToArray();

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x.ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower())
```